# Matplotlib: shift one series data on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have the following code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10, 5))
plt.suptitle('My Data', x = 0.5, y =  1.0, fontsize = '8')

for i in range(0,2):
    l1, = ax[i].plot(data_df['col_A'][101:200] , color = 'black')
    l2, = ax[i].plot(data_df['col_B'][101:200], color = 'red')

plt.show()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

And here is an output figure:

I am wondering if we could shift the entire red series to the left by 6 steps?

(I tried:

```
l2, = ax[i].plot(data_df_new['createvm_duration'][101-6:200-6], color = 'red')
```

which is not what I want because I want the x-axis ticks remain the same, but re-match of black and red peaks.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `shift` the column by *`-6`* before indexing it:

```
ax[i].plot(data_df['col_B'].shift(-6)[101:200], color = 'red')
```